# Reg ex for multiple characters

Tags: python, regex

I am trying capture regex for dates like:

```
14-July-2012-11_31_59
```

I do:

```
\d{2}-\w{4}-\d{4}-\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}$
```

But the month part here is 4 letters, it could be long e.g. September. 
That is the only variable. The length of digits is ok.

How do regex the word part to say at least 3 letters?

Comment: You can do `\w{3,}` - note that `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (alphanumerics + underscore).

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use regex for this?

Answer (score 2):

In general, `X{n,}` means *"`X` at least `n` times"*. But `\w` matches digits and underscores as well, you probably want to use `[a-zA-Z]{3,}` instead, since month-names shouldn't contain digits or underscores.

```
\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3,}-\d{4}-\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\d{2}-\w{3,}-\d{4}-\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this something you're looking for...

```
>>> a = '14-July-2012-11_31_59'
>>>
>>> pat  = r'\b\d{2}\-\w{3,}\-\d{2,4}\-\d{2}\_\d{2}\_\d{2}\b'
>>> regexp = re.compile(pat)
>>> m = regexp.match(a)
>>> m
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xa54c870>
>>> m.group()
'14-July-2012-11_31_59'
>>> m = regexp.match('14-September-2012-11_31_59')
>>> m.group()
'14-September-2012-11_31_59'
>>> m = regexp.match('14-September-12-11_31_59')
>>> m.group()
'14-September-12-11_31_59'
>>> m = regexp.match('14-Sep-12-11_31_59')
>>> m.group()
'14-Sep-12-11_31_59'
>>> m = regexp.match('14-Se-12-11_31_59')
>>> m.group()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
>>>
```